# Spring RestTemplate configuration strategies to call multiple rest services from a single API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a scenario where there is an aggregate endpoint to call multiple downstream systems which are RESTful and gives back the consolidated response from all these systems.

I am currently using a rest template that is configured as a singleton bean and injects it to the corresponding services to make the rest call. The RestTemplate is using the default CloseableHttpClient as the HttpClient, which will close the connections once the request is successful.

Would this be a good approach or would it be better if the rest template is configured per service that is calling its RESTful service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RestTemplate` is thread safe. You could use a pooling connection manager:

```
  @Bean
  public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager result = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    result.setMaxTotal(20);  // FIXME Consider making this value configurable
    return result;
  }

  @Bean
  public RequestConfig requestConfig() {
    RequestConfig result = RequestConfig.custom()
      // FIXME Consider making these values configurable
      .setConnectionRequestTimeout(2000)
      .setConnectTimeout(2000)
      .setSocketTimeout(2000)
      .build();
    return result;
  }

  @Bean
  public CloseableHttpClient httpClient(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager, RequestConfig requestConfig) {
    CloseableHttpClient result = HttpClientBuilder
      .create()
      .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
      .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
      .build();
    return result;
  }

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(HttpClient httpClient) {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
  }
```

And also important, you might need to change `RestTemplate`'s default settings based on observation / load tests, `RestTemplate` doesn't necessary use the whole pool to prevent a host from hijacking it.

You can read more at my blog [Troubleshooting Spring's RestTemplate Requests Timeout](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/27/Troubleshooting-Spring-RestTemplate-Requests-Timeout.html)

Comment: I have q question about shared data between the request who use the same connection from pool.  What is exactly shared between these requests? When we set up a cookie or header for each request with an interceptor, do you think theese informations are shared between request?

Comment: @bilgin, Nothing should be shared for the requests. RestTemplate uses a connection from the pool, which another request cannot use until the connection is returned to the pool. RestTemplate implementation is thread-safe.
If you re-use the same HttpEntity or Headers instances (maybe via static variables in a class) between requests, that's on you, not RestTemplate

Comment: Thanks @ootero but when we use the same connection each time a request is created and httpcontext keep som informations from the existing connection. My question was are cookies also used from previous connection? I didn't see in the code of appache http clien but i was not sure. I want to be sur that with a connection pool manager it wont mix user specifid cookies. With debugger, i sawthat there was a cookiestore with the same httpclient used for different request but i did not se the same cookies. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

From Spring Docs

> **RestTemplate**
>
> The RestTemplate is the central Spring class for client-side HTTP
>   access. Conceptually, it is very similar to the JdbcTemplate,
>   JmsTemplate, and the various other templates found in the Spring
>   Framework and other portfolio projects. This means, for instance, that
>   the RestTemplate is thread-safe once constructed, and that you can use
>   callbacks to customize its operations.

Hence you can create your `RestTemplate` its safe to share with multiple threads invoking a REST call simultaneously.

You should also consider cost of creating and destroying an instance. If each thread or each rest call creates a dedicated `RestTemplate` it will hamper your apps performance.

Ref: https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if you're injecting the services in the rest template if they have something in common. You can inject services with some common behavior in one rest template. This way you'll be able to implement some resuable code in say a parent class. Just because they all are a service, injection them in a single rest template might not be proper from design point of view.